# PSQLState compile error occurs in Eclipse

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I want to throw PSQLException in my Java program.

```
throw new PSQLException("serializable error", new PSQLState("40001"));
```

However, Eclipse doesn't allow compile my java program, getting an error:

> Cannot instantiate the type PSQLState

I use Postgres SQL database in the program. I have postgresql-42.2.5.jar library in the project. I imported these two classes, didn't help.

```
import org.postgresql.util.PSQLException; 
import org.postgresql.util.PSQLState;
```

Answer (score 0):

The class [`org.postgresql.util.PSQLState`](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/master/pgjdbc/src/main/java/org/postgresql/util/PSQLState.java) is an enum, so you can only use the values defined in that enum. You cannot create new values. However, your code should never need to instantiate a `PSQLException` at all, that exception is for use of the PostgreSQL JDBC Driver, not for user code.

If you need to throw a `SQLException` at all (and in my opinion user code normally shouldn't need to), you should use `java.sql.SQLException` (or one of its subclasses in the package `java.sql`), or define your own subclass, for example [`new SQLException(String reason, String SQLState)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/SQLException.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)).